# How to manage multi template in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm developing site which support templates in codeigniter. just like joomla / drupal how can i do that? my current site structure is each controller have it own template. header and footer templates are separate files. can any one tell me how can i do this?

Comment: This site is for specific programming questions, not general tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CodeIgniter-Template by Phil Sturgeon.

> CodeIgniter-Template is a Template library that helps your build
>   complex views with CodeIgniter. It has logic to work with themes &
>   modules and helps add your title, meta-data, breadcrumbs and partial
>   views.

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template

Comment: Need something for CI 3.0

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple flexible way to template in codeigniter
( via jeffrey way, nettuts ) 
So in your controller, at the end of the method....

```
 $data['content01'] = 'aboutus';
 $data['content02'] = 'contactform';
 $this->load->view( 'template_web', $data );
```

next in your views folder, in this example the file is called: template_web.php

```
        <?php 
        // sample header
            // you can also use to load nav bars, etc 
        $this->load->view('header'); 

            // check if unique content has been passed to template
            // you can have as many of these as you need
        if(isset($content01))
        $this->load->view($content01);

        if(isset($content02))
        $this->load->view($content02);

        if(isset($content03))
        $this->load->view($content03);

        // sample for a default footer
        $this->load->view('footer');
```

so we are loading a default header and footer, and then the content comes from the controller

the cool thing is if you need to, you can call different templates from your controller very quickly using the same setup

```
 $data['content01'] = 'contactform';
 $this->load->view( 'template_admin', $data );
```